# Ansible : sychronize files between two remote hosts given a specific group of hosts destination

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

i want to synchronize (copy) files between two remote hosts :.

Under my playbook , i'm running my tasks on several groups relativley to every task case.

**My playbook looks like this :**

```
---
- hosts: myHosts
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ ansi_user }}"
  vars:
    - buildServer_host : "127.78.11.04"
  roles:
    #... Different roles
    ...
    - { role: myRole }
```

**My inventory file looks like this :**

```
[myHosts]
myGroupA
myGroupB
myGroupC
```

**Under myRole , i ve this task :**

```
 - name: Copy  jars to API server 
   synchronize:
    src: "{{ Workspace_GEN_COLIS }}/{{item.item}}/target/{{item.stdout}}"
    dest: "/opt/application/i99was/{{RCD_DEF_VERSION}}/{{item.item}}.jar"
   with_items: "{{ jarFileNames.results }}"
   when:
    - ansible_host in groups['myGroupB']
   delegate_to: "{{buildServer_host }}"
```

As you can see : i want to transfer file from my **"buildServer_host"** to the re other remote destination which is only the group **"myGroupB"**

This fails , and i ve no idea why .

It seems like it doen't understand this : `ansible_host in groups['myGroupB']` as a destination host

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score -1):

The delegate_to is more than enough you don't need the when condition as the delegation would be done on the host you have selected in the delegate_to value.

Comment: i am using "delegate_to" to indicate my source server, the destination is in when condition